# how to deploy runbot odoo at odoo version 9?

Tags: odoo

I'm getting error in runbot odoo , 
here is the [log](http://runboot.portcities.net/runbot/static/build/02266-15646-09ee15/logs/job_20_test_all.txt).

I have installed runbot odoo in odoo version 9, runbot odoo module at
[github](http://github.com/odoo/odoo-extra) in branch master
and following runbot installation this [procedure](http://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/installing-and-configuring-your-own-runbot/).

I've got repository at `git@github:odoo/odoo`. After testing all, there is red thumb. Do I need to configure it or anything else to get green thumb?

Comment: I'm unable to open the log file you linked in. Could you maybe provide another link?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo8/addons_odoo/runbot/static/build/00837-8-0-8cb13c/openerp-gevent", line 5, in <module>
    import psycogreen.gevent
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 93, in __import__
    result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named psycogreen.gevent

Comment: On your platform may be GEVENT not install please install [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431096/gevent-does-not-install-properly-on-ubuntu] for gevent installation

Comment: Check this link may be it is helpful to you.. https://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/installing-and-configuring-your-own-runbot/

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip install psycogreen` and start again